# Quick Subsetting of Python Array

Tags: python, arrays

Coming from R to Python and I see why so many people love Python for data science. One useful feature of R is the quick subsetting. For example:

```
my_data = c(11,34,67,134,45,8,99,3543,1)
my_subset = c(3,8,1,6,4)
print(my_data[my_subset])
[1]  67  3543  11  8  134
```

One can programmatically generate subsets that satisfy various conditions and filter the data to that subset with a single instruction. How does one accomplish this in python?

Comment: If you have *NumPy* array, `arr = np.array([11,34,67,134,45,8,99,3543,1]); idx = np.array([3,8,1,6,4]); arr[idx-1]` should do it, Output -> `array([  67, 3543,   11,    8,  134])`

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go ahead and point out the obvious one-liner:

```
data = (11,34,67,134,45,8,99,3543,1)
indices = (3,8,1,6,4)
subset = [data[i] for i in indices]
print(subset)
```

Output:

```
[134, 1, 34, 99, 45]
```