# modify json object using a path from list

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list of lists where each list is the full path of where to modify the value.

```
import json
with open('main_data.json', 'r') as f:
    di = json.load(f)

lists = [[0, 'data', 'Hierarchical Namespace', 'LRS', 0, 'Archive'], [0, 'data', 'Hierarchical Namespace', 'LRS', 1, 'Archive'],...]
```

what I want to do is for each list value to a `di['list_path']=json.loads(value)`

so for the first 2 lists would be (if I am to do it manually)

```
v1 = di[0]['data']['Hierarchical Namespace']['LRS'][0]['Archive']
di[0]['data']['Hierarchical Namespace']['LRS'][0]['Archive'] = json.loads(v1)
v2 = di[0]['data']['Hierarchical Namespace']['LRS'][1]['Archive']
di[0]['data']['Hierarchical Namespace']['LRS'][1]['Archive'] = json.loads(v2)
...
```

Comment: Would the answer in comments help you?  I see they use numpy https://stackoverflow.com/q/66395530/2359945

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found something for you, using `exec` function:

```
# your original list
lists = [
    [0, 'data', 'Hierarchical Namespace', 'LRS', 0, 'Archive'], 
    [0, 'data', 'Hierarchical Namespace', 'LRS', 1, 'Archive'],
]

# this is the formated version (how would you see it as a string)
formatted_lists = []
for values in lists:
    formatted_values = []
    for value in values:
        if isinstance(value, str):
            # using __repr__ i cant see the string quotes inside a string
            formatted_values.append(value.__repr__())
        else:
            # i need to convert the int to string
            formatted_values.append(str(value))
    
    # template useful for executing it
    key_template = f"[{']['.join(formatted_values)}]"
    formatted_lists.append(key_template)

# iterating through templates and executing what you wanted
for formatted_value in formatted_lists:
    code = "di{} = json.loads({})".format(formatted_value, formatted_value)
    print(code)
    exec(code)
```

output (`what is executed`)

```
di[0]['data']['Hierarchical Namespace']['LRS'][0]['Archive'] = json.loads([0]['data']['Hierarchical Namespace']['LRS'][0]['Archive'])
di[0]['data']['Hierarchical Namespace']['LRS'][1]['Archive'] = json.loads([0]['data']['Hierarchical Namespace']['LRS'][1]['Archive'])
```

Comment: you are asking the execute a huge index operator accessing multiple times without writing by hand. ofc its not the prettiest.